# Running ejected project throws "Expo sdk required expo to run"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I created react-native project using create-react-native-app. In this I am importing Permissions module from expo,

```
import {Permissions} from "expo";
```

Later I realised that expo doesn't fullfill all my requirements (like social sharing etc), so I decided to eject the expo project. I ran following command to do so

```
"npm run eject"
```

After detaching, I installed expo as my project dependency to resolve imported Permissions module from expo.

```
"npm install expo"
```

Now when I run "npm run ios", I get this big error in my ios simulator.

[image]

Leads here is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you should now be using [ExpoKit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/expokit.html)

Comment: why is this needed?

Comment: Cant I simply eject using npm run eject and use expo as dependency? And then run "npm run ios" to start simulator?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with detaching from Expo, or that familiar with Expo to be honest just plain react-native development. But I believe when you eject from Expo you're now working with ExpoKit.

Comment: Based on [this comment](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/153#issuecomment-292374855) I think I'm right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you eject you're now using `ExpoKit` & no longer using the Expo sdk. The docs can be found [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html), [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/expokit.html) & [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/advanced-expokit-topics.html).

Comment: I got that, how do I resolve the error is my question.

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal did you follow the instructions to install the `ExpoKit podspec` ?

Comment: See there are three things, pure react-native project, react-native with expo kit, and expo project. Are you saying if I am using any expo dependency in expo project then I have to detach to expo kit project only?

Comment: No, only once you've already ejected from `expo` if you want to use their API you now need to use `ExpoKit` because you're project isn't built on the `expo sdk`

Comment: Ok, I ran "npm run eject" and I ran "npm run ios" then I see that error on top. What should I do next?

Comment: For starters, why did you eject?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165979/discussion-between-lokesh-agrawal-and-mattyk14).

Comment: I need social share

Comment: I tried all these but it ended up screwing my project. It looks like there is a lot to do ejecting project to expokit