# The Expo SDK requires Expo to run

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm running my project on expo. After running expo eject, I'm getting the following error:

> The Expo SDK requires Expo to run

Even for a brand new project I'm getting this error and I cannot do anything with expo anymore.
I run :

```
expo init Project1
```

and then going inside the Project1 direcotory and run:

```
expo start // and then click 'a' for running project on android emulator.
```

and emulator screen shows this error.

Comment: This seems to have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49032203/running-ejected-project-throws-expo-sdk-required-expo-to-run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have logged into the command line on your computer, log out and try reloading the app. Otherwise reinstall expo and try again.